# How to find keys in the HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>> which have one or more similar values in LinkedList<String>

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, hashmap, duplicates

So I am trying to solve the following problem, I used HashMap as DS to Store the input.

**Question:**
Given an address book contains a list of contacts which were imported from different sources (outlook, linkedin, facebook) where each contact has 1 or more email addresses, write a function to group all contacts which share any email together

**Input:**

```
C1: aaa@outlook.com, bbb@gmail.com
​C2: ddd@outlook.com
C3: bbb@gmail.com, aaa@outlook.com, ccc@yahoo.com
C4: ccc@yahoo.com
C5: ddd@outlook.com
C6: eee@outlook.com
```

I am looking for **output**:

```
((C1,C3,C4),(C2,C5),(C6))​
```

I tried to get all values from hashmap into a hashset and then if the key in hashmap contains the value from set, I add the key to a result arraylist.

The code I am using is :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, LinkedList> entry: hm.entrySet()){
                //System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());  
                set.addAll(entry.getValue());
        }
        ArrayList<String> res1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map.Entry<String, LinkedList> entry: hm.entrySet()){
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Iterator<String> curr = entry.getValue().iterator();
            System.out.println(hm.entrySet());
            while(curr.hasNext()){
                System.out.println("Current= "+curr.next());
                if(set.contains(curr.next())){
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                    res1.add(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }   
        System.out.println(set);
        System.out.println(res1);
```

The output I am getting is :

```
[C3=[aaa@gmail.com, bbb@outlook.com, ccc@yahoo.com], C4=[ccc@yahoo.com], C5=   
[ddd@outlook.com], C6=[eee@outlook.com], C1=[bbb@outlook.com, 
ddd@outlook.com], C2=[aaa@gmail.com]]

Current= aaa@gmail.com
C3
Current= ccc@yahoo.com
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:890)
    at com.logicBuilding.MQ3_HashTable.getCommon(MQ3_HashTable.java:45)
    at com.logicBuilding.MQ3_HashTable.main(MQ3_HashTable.java:7)
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Current= "+curr.next()); if(set.contains(curr.next())){`  the second call of the `next()` method is done withoud checking if another item is available...

Comment: Your output doesn't quite make sense to me. Why is C1 in a group with C4? And is C6 allowed to be in a group alone, even though it has 0 similar values?

Comment: @4castle C1 and C3 has aaa@yahoo.com in common and C3 and C4 has ccc@yahoo.com in common and therefore they belong to same person!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code of yours:

```
            System.out.println("Current= "+curr.next());
            if(set.contains(curr.next())){
```

with

```
            String current = curr.next();
            System.out.println("Current= " + current);
            if(set.contains(current)) {
```

to avoid calling the `next()` method without even checking if a next element is available. Also your your `if` condition wants to check if the string you are currently looking at in is in your `set`, not the next one already.

Comment: Thanks, now the final part is how do I group the keys like this 
((C1,C3,C4),(C2,C5),(C6))​, I got  output as [C3, C3, C3, C4, C5, C6, C1, C1, C2]

Comment: You can not use `ArrayList` for grouping.

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: If each of your groups has a unique key, why don't use a `Map` structure again?

Comment: Although the  String current = curr.next() works; I did not understand how was it different from my solution ?